# How to plot tick labels on top of the data points on Mollweide projection with matplotlib and seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, astronomy

I'm a phd candidate in extragalactic astrophysics and I want to plot the coordinates of the galaxies that I'm studying on a Mollweide projection coloring them by the amount of reddening their light experience due to Milky Way dust.

So here's what I'm doing:

The modules that I'm importing and using in the following piece of code are:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
```

First, I define a plane with the Mollweide projection:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection='mollweide')
```

Then I plot my data, and draw a colorbar:

```
plt.scatter(np.radians(sample.ra-180), np.radians(sample.dec), marker = '.', c = get_EBV(sample.ra,sample.dec), cmap = colormap, vmin = 0, vmax = 1.5, linewidths = 0., zorder = 10)

plt.colorbar(orientation = 'horizontal', shrink = 0.8)
```

Here, `sample.ra` and `sample.dec` are the coordinates of the galaxies on my sample and `get_EBV(ra,dec)` is a function that I defined to get the galaxy's reddening.

Now I define the labels and plot them, using a `zorder` bigger than the one of the data points to try to get the labels on top:

```
tick_labels = np.array([150, 120, 90, 60, 30, 0, 330, 300, 270, 240, 210])
tick_labels_y = np.array([-75, -60, -45, -30, -15, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75])
ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels, zorder = 15)
ax.set_yticklabels(tick_labels_y, zorder = 15)
```

Then I plot the labels, which should not be something related to the issue:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{RA[\degree]}$')
ax.xaxis.label.set_fontsize(12)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathrm{Dec[\degree]}$')
ax.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(12)
```

Result:
[image]

Which is very close to what I'm going for, but I can't get over the fact that the data points are plotted on top of the axis label, what could I do to plot the labels on top of the data or to shift the labels to a place where they would not be in obstructed?

Note: I tried to set the `zorder` of the labels to get them in front of the data and it did not work. Also, in this example I'm using `tick_labels`, but the problem already existed when I wasn't using them.

Comment: This seems to be caused by `seaborn`; `matplotlib` itself doesn't have this problem. Partial workaround is to set the the `zorder` of `scatter` to some small value, but then the `grid` lines are also in front of the scatter points.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question to ask specifically about seaborn. I followed your workaround and [got this](http://i.imgur.com/4uyLQSt.png), as you predicted, the grid lines are now on top of the data points, but this is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, seeing that example, It actually makes sense to plot the grid lines on top of the markers :)